# How to delete multiple processes using linq easily

Tags: c#, linq

I have lets say two processes: notepad and taskmgr open. I want to kill those two or few more processes how can i do this? 
So far i came up with this by googling around:

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName == "notepad,taskmgr").ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());
```

not sure how to differentiate between two processes above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That linq query looks to be only finding a process when its name is "notepad,taskmgr".  To get both, use a query like this:

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName == "notepad" || p.ProcessName == "taskmgr").ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());
```

If you're going to be adding more processes, you might want to do something like this:

```
var processNamesToKill = new List<string> { "notepad", "taskmgr", "someotherprocess" };
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => processNamesToKill.Contains(p.ProcessName)).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());
```

You can then add other processes to that list.  As for figuring out what ones you've found, in your ForEach, you can access the name by `y.ProcessName` and use it in a conditional, where needed.

Edit: add `.exe` to those process names if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Create a list or array with your processes to be killed, then check the list for the name of the process

```
List<string> killme = new List<string> { "notepad", "taskmgr" }

Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => killme.Contains(p.ProcessName)).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());
```

One Liner, which was in an answer that was deleted:

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => new[] {"notepad", "taskmgr"}.Contains(p.ProcessName)).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());
```

Comment: is this the best way to do this? Is there a one line solution? I guess not right?

Comment: i'd suggest a `Set` of strings instead of a `List`, but that's just me

Comment: @NoviceMe Someone posted a one line solution where an array was constructed within the linq statement, but I would consider this to be more readable

Comment: @NoviceMe Updated with a one liner, though I prefer the first answer

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do this?

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName == "notepad" || p.ProcessName == "taskmgr")
    .ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());
```

What I would do, if I were you, would be to just do it 1 name at a time.  It's a lot easier to understand for anyone reading the code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        killProcess("notepad.exe");
        killProcess("taskmgr");
    }

    public static void killProcess(string name)
    {
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(name))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think the method `killAllProccesses(IEnumerable<string> processesToKill)` is rather readable to the consumer.

Comment: @Servy   that's another way to interface it.  I still wouldn't shove it all in a linq command though.

Comment: I would use [a real foreach loop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), but using the `Where` as other's have isn't a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

if the rest of your linq works, that where should just be something like

```
... Where( p => p.ProcessName == "notepad" || p.ProcessName == "taskmgr" ) ...
```

otherwise, you might want to make a set of the process names to kill, like

```
var set = new HashSet<string>() { "notepad.exe", "taskmgr.txt", "someotherthing.exe" };
... linq .. Where( p=> set.Contains( p.ProcessName ) )...
```

or other various join operations on the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var processesToKill = new [] {"notepad", "iexplorer"};
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => processesToKill.Contains(p.ProcessName)).ToList();
        processes.ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of processes you want to kill, you can use `Contains`, as doing `p => p.ProcessName == "notepad,taskmgr"` won't work (No process will have the name "notepad,taskmgr", adding a comma has no special meaning)

So instead try something like

```
var processesToKill = new Collection<string> { "notepad", "taskmgr" };

foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => processesToKill.Contains(p)))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill all processes by name purely with LINQ, in a single line, without having an error thrown, you can use...

```cs
Process.GetProcessesByName("WinStore.App").ToList().Where(p => p.HasExited == false).ToList().ForEach(s => s.Kill());
```

Kind of obtuse at first... but it will ensure the processes it is killing have actually ended. Sometimes you'll get an error if you try to kill a process that is not running but has not yet exited (if it's currently exiting and is in *process purgatory*...)